# How to find a path with minimal node value in a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, path, tree

I have  undirected  graph G(n,m). And each vertex has a value  v-i. And what polynomial complexity algorithm can  help me to find a path s-t so that maximum value of the node between s-t is minimal among other possible path's maximal node values.

I hope it is clear. Thank  you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  [Dijkstra's algorithm using a priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Using_a_priority_queue). Instead of keeping track of the *distance*, you keep track of max(v<sub>i</sub>), but the rest of the algorithm can be used as-is.

Comment: Thank you!, but can u  clarify how exactly i make sure that maximum  v  in path is a minimum among other path

Comment: The priority queue takes care of that. It makes sure that when you pull an entry (path) from it, it is the one with the minimum value that you stored with it. [And the value that you store on the queue with the path, is the max(vi)].